# Partner licenses and Roles

Tags: profile, licenses, roles

1. description

When I change the License by change Profiled on query, I find this
User Role disappear, and I can't select a role in picklist. Then I
want use query to change the user Role, Salesforce give me a

```
error '[object Object]: Cannot assign roles to a disabled portal user: Role ID'
```

So, I should do something to assign the role???? Additional, I change
the Partner's License by query from Partner Login User to Partner
User,and the Partner's Permission is delected,what's more,the
Partner's role is alse delected. Before ,the Role have no the private
role，he was a Data Partners, individual customers.

I want to know why the role is delected and how can i do something to
give the user role again.And i hope you can help me to learn how the
role is worked.I am sorry my English is poor, please give me more
advice about to submit question,Thanks

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A7oYVSAZ

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include more details.  What is the original license and what is the new license type?  Regarding the error, the text is pretty clear.  The error is pretty clear.  Have you deactivated the user?  Please [edit] your post.